# iPhone dev - How can I display a google map in an app without using the browser? And other map questions

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, gps, maps

I'm making an iPhone application that I want to take in a bunch of addresses and display them on a map using different colored pins to mark the different addresses. First of all, is this possible? Secondly, I want a way to do it without having to open up the map in a browser, but display it directly as a view. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it is possible Tim, check here:

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. You can put a MKMapView directly into the view. This can be dragged and dropped in the XIB file! Make sure that you also include the Map Kit framework in your project, too. For addresses, I would look at the link to the tutorial Jacky Boy gave.